# Is there any risk to lose data if reinstall ubuntu-desktop?

Tags: intel-graphics, desktop-environments

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Have been facing graphics issue while the system is booting. I found different solutions. Finally wanted to run

```
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
```

If I do the above command can I lose any data or will fix the [graphics issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)?

Comment: You shouldn't but backup just in case that you thought of it is a good sign!

Answer (score 1):

> can I lose any data

Unlikely. Worst that happens is that the reinstall is interupted leaving an unusable system. If that happens a live session can be used to extract personal data. But ... if you have anything important you should already have a backup and can restore files from that.

> or will fix the graphics issue?

Unlikely; in my experience if you have a problem best to do is to focus on the problem and check log files for errors you can search on. If you have problems with graphics all you would(/should need to do is purge the graphics driver (so not just the uninstall option), reboot so it starts using the generic driver and then install another version of the graphics driver. That should fix any problems with a graphics driver.

You will have better luck installing a newer version (18.04 if you want to stick to LTS). Your problem might be a bug in the driver used for 16.04 and have a fix in a newer version.

> Have been facing graphics issue while the system is booting.

Too vague to help you with. Like state above: I myself would dive into the different logs, check for error notices and messages that indicate a problem and search for those. And if that fails install the newest (LTS) Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot for writing such a descriptive suggestions :)

Comment: I just wanted to run the above command on the top but it shows "E: unable to find ubuntu package" and "E: unable to find ubuntu desktop", any idea?

Comment: it is ubuntu-desktop not ubuntu desktop